# Como desplegar una foto local con el evento Click de un boton en angular 8/9

Tags: html, css, angular, imagen, input

tengo el siguiente codigo, en donde cree un input de tipo imagen con el evento click que hace referencia a una funcion llamada "mostrarfoto()" (linea 12 esta el input)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

- La clase mostrarfoto(), es la siguiente (tiene un mensaje de alert para comprobar que la funcion estaba siendo ejecutada y si efectivamente lo esta)}(LINEA 12)
  [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me gustaria hacer que al presionar sobre ese input en la pagina, desplegara una fotografia local, solo cuando se clicke,

- ¿como puedo hacer esto?
- ¿ cual es la funcion que debo introducir en mostrarfoto() ?
- ¿Para este caso es mas recomendable usar un boton o un input?

Estoy utilizando Angular 8, y trabajando principalmente con html y css.

Comment: cual fotografia quieres que se desplegue, una que suba el usuario o una local?

Comment: Hola, una fotografia local, que esta almacenada en assets

Comment: Hola Kenny, bienvenido al foro. Te recomiendo eliminar las imágenes y agregar el código como tal a tu pregunta. Es una de las reglas/recomendaciones del foro. Segundo, quieres mostrar la foto en tu template al hacer click al botón, correcto?.

Comment: Hola RRGT19, si! correcto! al hacer click sobre el input, se despliegue una imagen, y que al volver a clickearlo esta se cierre